# Evaluation of command changes its value?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgf-umlcd

I am trying to create UML class diagrams using pgf-umlcd and ran into problems. Ultimately I want to align the classes using a specified **horizontal spacing**. I also need to be able to set the **text width**.

I want to be able to address different anchors. My calculation should be ok, however the command seems to be evaluated to different values.

I made an example with two classes. One uses the 'variable' and the other one its value.

Code to reproduce:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgf-umlcd}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[font=\small,outer frame sep=0,outer sep=0]
    \newcommand{\currTextWidth}{7.5cm}
    \newcommand{\desiredSpacing}{0cm}

    \newcommand{\pad}{\the\dimexpr \pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/inner xsep}*2\relax} % calculate padding
    
    \newcommand{\overAllWidth}{\the\dimexpr \currTextWidth + (\pad)\relax}
    \newcommand{\currSpacing}{\the\dimexpr \desiredSpacing + \overAllWidth / 2\relax}

    % this resembles the referenced class
    \begin{class}[text width=\currTextWidth]{RandomClass}{0,0}
       \operation[0]{+ doSomething(): void}
    \end{class}

    % calculated values
    \node at (0,1.5)  {overAllWidth = \overAllWidth};
    \node at (0,1)  {currSpacing = \currSpacing};

    % this result would be fine
    \begin{class}[text width=\currTextWidth,right=109.78008pt]{ClassUsingValue}{RandomClass.north}
    \end{class}

    % but I want to use the 'variable' here
    \begin{class}[text width=\currTextWidth,right=\currSpacing]{ClassUsingVariable}{RandomClass.south}
    \end{class}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image: variable evaluation ev]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't make all that much sense to use `\newcommand` rather than `\newlength` here, at least to me. Why not use LaTeX lengths rather than turning LaTeX macros into dimensions?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgf-umlcd,calc}
\newlength\desiredSpacing
\newlength\currTextWidth
\newlength\pad
\newlength\overAllWidth
\newlength\currSpacing

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[font=\small,outer frame sep=0,outer sep=0]
  \setlength\desiredSpacing{0cm}
  \setlength\currTextWidth{7.5cm}
  \setlength\pad{\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/inner xsep}*2}
  \setlength\overAllWidth{\currTextWidth + \pad}
  \setlength\currSpacing{\desiredSpacing + \overAllWidth / 2}
  
  % this resembles the referenced class
  \begin{class}[text width=\currTextWidth]{RandomClass}{0,0}
    \operation[0]{+ doSomething(): void}
  \end{class}
  
  % calculated values
  \node at (0,1.5)  {overAllWidth = \the\overAllWidth};
  \node at (0,1)  {currSpacing = \the\currSpacing};
  
  % this result would be fine
  \begin{class}[text width=\currTextWidth,right=109.78008pt]{ClassUsingValue}{RandomClass.north}
  \end{class}
  
  % but I want to use the 'variable' here
  \begin{class}[text width=\currTextWidth,right=\currSpacing]{ClassUsingVariable}{RandomClass.south}
  \end{class}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: aligned result]

Comment: `\newlength` should be in the preamble, not inside the `tikzpicture`

Comment: Awesome! I didn't know about newlength. Thank you!

Comment: @egreg Why? I wondered about that because I usually put it outside the environment, but I wasn't sure I had an actual reason. And does it need to be in the preamble or just outside the `tikzpicture`?

Comment: @egreg Should anything which assigns a register be in the preamble?

Comment: Generally speaking, yes.

Comment: @egreg Thanks. Why in the preamble specifically? I usually put stuff there, but sometimes I might put `\newlength` or something in the document (but usually at the top level). What difference does `\begin{document}` make?

Comment: @cfr It's the best place: you know *where* you're allocating all registers.

Comment: @egreg That makes sense. Just occasionally it makes sense (to me) to put something later so I remember why I did it. (Usually this involves Beamer for some reason.)

Comment: @Gutenberg I just realised there is sometimes a good reason to use macros rather than lengths or dimensions. Storing values in macros is more accurate e.g. you keep `0.00031...` versus `0.0003pt`. In a lot of cases, that won't matter, but sometimes it does.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that when you're inside `class` the value of `inner xsep` is zero, but it's different when you're typesetting text in a `\node`.

If I add

```
\showthe\dimexpr\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/inner xsep}\relax
```

inside the `class` environment, I get `0.0pt`, but when I add it inside a node I get `3.08224pt`.

If you want to freeze the value of `inner xsep`, you need `\edef` rather than `\newcommand` (that's the same as `\def`).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgf-umlcd}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[font=\small,outer frame sep=0,outer sep=0]
\def\currTextWidth{7.5cm}
\def\desiredSpacing{0cm}
\edef\pad{\the\dimexpr \pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/inner xsep}*2\relax} % calculate padding
\edef\overAllWidth{\the\dimexpr \currTextWidth + (\pad)\relax}
\edef\currSpacing{\the\dimexpr \desiredSpacing + \overAllWidth / 2\relax}
% this resembles the referenced class
\begin{class}[text width=\currTextWidth]{RandomClass}{0,0}
   \operation[0]{+ doSomething(): void}
\end{class}
% calculated values
\node at (0,1.5)  {overAllWidth = \overAllWidth};
\node at (0,1)  {currSpacing = \currSpacing};
% this result would be fine
\begin{class}[text width=\currTextWidth,right=106.69783pt]{ClassUsingValue}{RandomClass.north}
\end{class}
% but I want to use the 'variable' here
\begin{class}[text width=\currTextWidth,right=\currSpacing]{ClassUsingVariable}{RandomClass.south}
\end{class}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Be careful in the naming of such commands, because `\def` and `\edef` will silently (locally) change the meaning of existing commands.

For safety, you can still use `\newcommand`, though:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[font=\small,outer frame sep=0,outer sep=0]
\newcommand{\currTextWidth}{7.5cm}
\newcommand{\desiredSpacing}{0cm}
\ExpandArgs{ne}\newcommand{\pad}{\the\dimexpr \pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/inner xsep}*2\relax}
\ExpandArgs{ne}\newcommand{\overAllWidth}{\the\dimexpr \currTextWidth + (\pad)\relax}
\ExpandArgs{ne}\newcommand{\currSpacing}{\the\dimexpr \desiredSpacing + \overAllWidth / 2\relax}
% this resembles the referenced class
[...]
```

because `\ExpandArgs` jumps by default over the token following its argument; with `ne` we're instructing to do nothing to the first braced group following and to fully expand the contents of the second braced group following.

[image]